# Checkbox check event is not getting prevented

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a set of set of checkboxes on which I want to restrict to check maximum of one. If the choice needs to be changed then first checked ones need to be unchecked but maximum limit needs to be one.
Here is the jquery code.

```
 $('#ReportRow').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', (function (event) {
 alert("Hi");
 var checkedReportValues = $('#ReportRow input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
           return this.value;
           }).get();

           if ($("#ReportRow input:checkbox:checked").length > 1) {
                    return false;
           }
           alert(checkedReportValues);
 })
 );
```

Here, the above code is restricting only one checkbox to be checked but when I am trying to check other, they first are being checked and then unchecked. Where I am doing wrong ?

Here is the dynamically created HTML.

```
 //Add Code to Create CheckBox dynamically by accessing data from Ajax for the application selected above
            var Reports = " User, Admin, Detail, Summary";
            var arrReportscheckBoxItems = Reports.split(',');
            var reportscheckBoxhtml = ''
            for (var i = 0; i < arrReportscheckBoxItems.length; i++) {
                reportscheckBoxhtml += '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label style="font-weight: 600; color: #00467f !important;"><input type="checkbox" value=' + arrReportscheckBoxItems[i] + '>' + arrReportscheckBoxItems[i] + '</label>';
            }

            //Add Submit button here
            reportscheckBoxhtml += '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" id="SubmitReport" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>';

            $('#ReportRow').html(reportscheckBoxhtml);
```

Comment: provide your html to?

Comment: `If the choice needs to be changed then first checked ones need to be unchecked but maximum limit needs to be one.` use `<input type = "radio">`

Comment: @MayankPandey Added HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: uncheck all other checkboxes except clicked one inside click event handler, like below

```js
$('#ReportRow').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
  $('#ReportRow input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked",false);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ReportRow">
<input type="checkbox">one
  <input type="checkbox">Two
  <input type="checkbox">Three
  <input type="checkbox">Four
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if ($("#ReportRow input:checkbox:checked").length > 1) {
                return false;
       }
```

is saying you want to uncheck the checkbox. It's doing exactly what you tell it to do. Just a comment: Users may be confused since checkboxes are meant to check multiple selections. Radio buttons are designed for being able to select only one option.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning false from the function when there is a checkbox already selected, which is preventing the checkbox selection.

```
 if ($("#ReportRow input:checkbox:checked").length > 1) {
                    return false;
           }
```

Do something like this:

```
$('#ReportRow').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', (function (event) {
     alert("Hi");
     var curCheckBox = this;
     $('#ReportRow').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function()  {
        if(this === curCheckBox)
            $(this).attr("checked",true);
        else
            $(this).attr("checked",false);
    });
    alert(checkedReportValues);
});
```